# convert ssom to csom of Adding Document Librarty to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts, csom

I am trying to convert below code SSOM to CSOM of adding adding Document Library to SharePoint 2013 page.

SSOM

```
SPFile ofile = web.Getfile("Pages/Home.aspx");
using(SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = ofile.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
{
    SPList oList = web.Lists["TestDocument"];
    SPView oView = oList.Views["WebPart"];
    XsltListViewWebPart aWp = new XsltListViewWebPart
    {
        ListName = oList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper(),
        Title = "Practice Announcements",
        ViewContentTypeId = oView.ContentTypeId.ToString(),
        ViewGuid = oView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper(),
        Width = "400px",
        ChromeType = PartChromeType.TitleOnly
    };
    wpm.AddWebPart(aWp,"CenterLeftColumn",1);
    oList.Update();
}
```

Any article, link can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Webpart XML content for the document library,below XML schema worked with me while I was adding listviewwebparts to a page in CSOM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="ListUrl" type="string">Shared%20Documents</property>
        <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Sample code:

```
            var wpXML = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3'>
    <metaData>
      <type name='Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name='ListUrl' type='string'>Shared%20Documents</property>
        <property name='MissingAssembly' type='string'>Cannot import this Web Part.</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>";

            var page = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/test/SitePages/wiki1.aspx");

            var wpm = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
            ctx.Load(wpm);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            var importedWebPart = wpm.ImportWebPart(wpXML);
            var webPart = wpm.AddWebPart(importedWebPart.WebPart, "mainContent", 0);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, can we do without XML? Is there any other way by which we can add document library to the page without using XML

Comment: Per my knowledge, we have to use XML to insert web part to page.

Comment: Thanks Michael, code given by you is working as expected. Can we select default view while adding document library?